# Detecting 'unusual behavior' using machine learning with Redis and Python?

Tags: machine-learning, anomaly-detection

I am developing client application using python . It will listening the redis queue (subpub) and doing some suppression and aggregations .

Eg msg from redis :- 
CPU 80% full critical
CPU 80% full critical
CPU 80% full critical
CPU 80% full recovered
CPU 90% full critical
CPU 90% full critical
CPU 90% full recovered

After the client it's look like below

CPU 80% full critical count 3
CPU 90% full critical count 2

after recovering I am not keep track any messages

Problem is,due to application unusual behavior sometimes i am getting more alerts frequently , it's like below .

CPU 80% full critical
CPU 80% full recovered 
CPU 80% full critical
CPU 80% full recovered
CPU 80% full critical
CPU 80% full recovered
CPU 80% full critical
CPU 80% full recovered

I need to identify this . how can use machine learning for this ?